# Regex, válido se houver palavras específicas em qualquer ordem

Tags: regex

Pra mim é sempre melhor exemplificar os casos de regex. Veja só:

- **Palavra1**- Válido
- **Palavra2**- Válido
- **Palavra1** **Palavra2**- Válido
- **Palavra2** **Palavra1**- Válido
- **Palavra1** **Palavra1**- Invalido
- **Palavra2** **Palavra2**- Invalido

Mas digamos que sejam 5 ou 6 palavras, fica muito dispendioso escrever TODAS as possibilidades

Answer (score 3):

É dificil com regex saber se há uma sequencia sem repetições, mas é fácil saber se há repetição de palavras. Usando um grupo de captura podes verificar se uma dada palavra volta a aparecer na string.

Podes usar uma regex assim:

```
 \b(\w+)\s[\s\w]*\1
```

Ela procura uma palavra `\b(\w+)` seguida de um espaço `\s` (para termos a certeza que virá outra palavra), e depois procura na string uma repetição do que foi capturado na anteriormente com `\1`.

#### exemplo de regex: https://regex101.com/r/nQ8bW7/1

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/28fmmrna/

Comment: Ok! Bem eu não sabia desse \1 , bem, ai é fácil, primeiro eu verifico se só contem as palavras permitidas, depois verifico se não há repetição !